# Distribution of one Poisson variable relative to another

Tags: poisson-distribution, conditional-probability, skellam-distribution

Assume A and B are two independent Poisson random numbers with means a and b.

What is the conditional distribution of A **given** that A`>`B, A=B and A`<`B respectively, i.e. out of all the samples, what is the distribution of A when its larger, equal or smaller than B?

Note that I am **not** asking for the distribution of the largest or smallest of the two. I am specifically interested in the first variable.

I can use Skellam to get probabilities for the occurrence of each of these 3 scenarios, but this does not help me getting the distribution of A itself. I fear they can not be Poisson since Prob (A=0)=0 when A`>`B.

Comment: 1. This sounds rather like routine bookwork. Is this related to work for some subject?  2. Can you write down one or two formulas for conditional probability?

Comment: Apologies if the notation isnt very clear, thought the problem is very cleanly described. Feel free to update the original question with different letters. Its not homework or someone elses original problem, but something that I would like to know. Thanks

Comment: If getting the whole distribution is to complicated, can I get the mean of A in those 3 scenarios directly?

Comment: The entire distribution calculation isn't so difficult if you don't mind expressions involving sums you'll usually need to evaluate numerically.

Comment: A sum as shown for the case P(A=i|A=B) as shown below is perfectly fine. How would that look in the other two cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's tackle the equality problem first, then the other two:

$$P(A=i|A=B) = \frac{P(A=i)P(B=i)}{\sum_j P(A=j)P(B=j)}$$

$$= \frac{\exp(-a)a^i/i! \cdot \exp(-b)b^i/i! }
  {\sum_j \exp(-a)a^j/j! \cdot \exp(-b)b^j/j!}$$

$$= \frac{ (ab)^i /(i!)^2 }{ \sum_j (ab)^j/(j!)^2}\,,\: i=0,1,2,...$$

Which can be further simplified but I think the principle is clear. Even this form is quite suitable for numerical calculation (the values decrease quite rapidly to the right of the mode, so good accuracy can usually be had simply by truncating the series at a sensible place. If the parameters are very large you might need to be a bit more sophisticated about it.

I simulated 10000 values each from $A$ and $B$ with $a=2$ and $b=1$ to compare with that calculation. It turned out that 21.4% of the simulations gave A=B, and the proportion of A at each value when that was the case was as shown in the histogram:

[image: Histogram of simulated A given A=B vs theoretical calculation]

The blue points represent the corresponding theoretical calculation above. As you can see the values are very close together.

---

$$P(A=i|A<B) = \frac{P(A=i)\sum_{k=i+1}^\infty P(B=k)}{\sum_j (P(A=j)\sum_{k=j+1}^\infty P(B=k))}$$

$$ = \frac{P(A=i)S_B(i)}{\sum_j P(A=j)S_B(j)}$$

Where $S_B$ is the survivor function for variable $B$. It would be possible to cancel factors of $e^{-(a+b)}$ as in the previous case but it's convenient to leave them there and do the calculations directly in this form.

Here's that calculation done in R code for that cut off somewhere reasonable for the parameters involved (2 and 1 again):

```
i <- 0:20
p <- dpois(i,2)*ppois(i,1,lower.tail=FALSE)
p <- p/sum(p)
```

And here's a comparison with simulation:

[image: Plot of the A<B case for Poissons with respective means 2 and 1]

---

Now the $A>B$ case:

$$P(A=i|A>B) = \frac{P(A=i)\sum_{k=0}^{i-1} P(B=k)}{\sum_j (P(A=j)\sum_{k=0}^{j-1} P(B=k))}$$

$$ = \frac{P(A=i)F_B(i-1)}{\sum_j P(A=j)F_B(j-1)}\,,\: i=1,2,...$$

And again we can simulate and compare simulated proportions with the above algebraic calculations:

[image: Plot of the A<B case for Poissons with respective means 2 and 1]

Comment: Thats great and converges quickly as you say. Slick to implement since the denominator is independent of i (so can just be calculated once) and the numerator can be done recursively.

Comment: Above is clear. Having seen the first case i was hoping that the second one would also include some simplifications, but it this seems impossible and just have to iterate over all the probabilites as described. On this basis the case of A>B is straight forward.

Comment: Some cancellation in that case is possible but not really helpful. Indeed we could, if we preferred, avoid the cancellation in the first case and write slightly simpler code to calculate the probabilities (but it hardly matters either way; one may choose whichever is convenient).